# which one has better performance: patindex and like

Tags: t-sql, sybase, sybase-asa

in a query where condition clause. to check if string a contain b, I have a few options with T-SQL(Sybase):

```
a like '%b%'
charindex(b,a)>0
patindex('%b%', a)>0
```

which one has better performance?

Comment: I like charindex but it will depend on your data and the query it is in.

Comment: Seems easy enough to test yourself. There are too many variable to give you a 100% correct / non-opinionated answer.

Comment: I have same question for sqlserver, did anyone get an answer?